# Diferença entre REJECT e DROP no iptables

Tags: linux, iptables

Qual a diferença de usar o `REJECT` ou `DROP` na configuração do *iptables*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basicamente funciona assim, quando utilizado o **DROP** o pacote recebido é barrado em modo silencioso(**Stealth**), ou seja, **nada** é retornado para o remetente. Particularmente quando preciso barrar pacotes em portas eu prefiro utilizar essa regra, pois em um possível ataque, nada é retornado.

Já o **REJECT**, o pacote é barrado assim como no DROP, porém uma resposta é devolvida informando o erro(Pacote UDP retorna um ICMP tipo 3, se for TCP será do tipo TCP reset).